# Material UI Popper Styling

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui, styling, popper.js

[What I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpi4H.png)

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvPDu.png)

I'm trying to achieve the following using flex. What's the best approach to handle this?
I'm finding it difficult to separate the gap between the two text fields (text && secondaryText)

```
popper: createStyles({
        root: {
            backgroundColor: white,
            borderRadius: 4,
            boxShadow: "0 2px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
            zIndex: 1301,
            maxHeight: 200,
            overflowY: "auto",
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
        },
    }),
};

<Popper
       className={toClassName(classes.popper)}
       >             
         {children} // Component AutocompleteSelection
</Popper>

const AutocompleteSelection: FC<AutocompleteSelectionProps> = ({
    text,
    secondaryText,
}): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = useMakeStyles(baseStyles) as Properties;
    return (
        <ListItem styles={listItem}>
            <Typography classes={classes.typography}>
                {text}
                {secondaryText}
            </Typography>
        </ListItem>
    );
};

const baseStyles: Properties = {
    listItem: createStyles({
        root: {
            "&:hover": {
                backgroundColor: greyTwo,
            },
        },
    }),
    typography: createStyles({
        root: {
            fontSize: 14,
            lineHeight: 1,
        },
    }),
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, to display `secondaryText` floated `right` in a `flex` display, to could use `marginLeft: "auto"` in `secondayText` class like:

```
  <Typography class={classes.typography}>
    <Typography class={classes.text}>{"hello"}</Typography>
    <Typography class={classes.secondaryText}>{"there"}</Typography>
  </Typography>
```

And style:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  typography: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  text: {},
  secondaryText: {
    marginLeft: "auto"  // secondary text floated to right
  }
}));
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-35fkl?file=/src/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I went with this approach.

Comment: No problem :) :)